# ASP.Net Model (GET) not displaying value

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Mapping my model yet value is not setting...Very strange,

```
public ActionResult Appointment(string date = null, string id)
{
    // Do stuff
    var rId = _resource.Find(id)
    var model = new ViewModels.AppointmentNew()
    {
        ResourceId = rId;
    }
    return View("Appointment", model);
}
```

Html\View

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ResourceId)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
```

HTML Render

```
<input id="ResourceId" name="ResourceId" type="hidden" value="">
```

When looking at the viewdata > Model
[image]

The value has been set against ResourceId...
Ideas?

Comment: The code you have shown will work fine - its the code you have not shown causing the issue. What does `<div>@Model.ResourceId</div>` display. And if its correct, put a breakpoint on the `return View(..)` line and check the values in `ModelState` for that property

Comment: Hey, when using @Model.ResourceId, 96763419-da4c-4d60-8602-cb78f73b1660 is displayed, the  return View("Appointment", model); does contain the id

Comment: You did not answer the 2nd part of my question :)

Comment: ModelState say 0 errors, however I do note the issue only occurs if I dont pass a date into the controller, (if no date then I then set it manually), this looks to be the issue, however not sure why as I need to let a null date be passed, ideas?

Comment: I did not ask about `ModelState` errors - just about the values:). Add `ModelState`.Clear()` immediately before `return View(...)`- what is the output of the input now?